# Does the FIX protocol offers a solution for ciphering data?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I have a program that uses FIX protocol and the QuickFix engine (in my case, for c++) in order to do inter process communication. My question is, since the data is transferred in plaintext, does the standard of the protocol OR the engine offers a cryptography solution to cipher/decipher the data? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SSL with QuickFIX.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quickfix/quickfix/master/README.SSL

You could also send data through stunnel. https://www.stunnel.org/

The protocol itself does not offer such functionality although you could specify the encryption method through tag 98/EncryptMethod.